# Can't connect QuickSight to SQL Server - "Your database generated a SQL exception" error

Tags: sql-server, amazon-quicksight

Someone having the same error while trying to connect to Quicksight from SQL Server?

Any thought of what might be wrong?

Obs: I Have view only user with remote access.

[image: error message]

Comment: Is there a way to verify that the Sql Server instance attempted to be connected to has been started?

Comment: Maybe with sql error log, yet im view only user

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled '`Named Pipes`'?

> Open the 'SQL Server Configuration' application.
>
> In the left pane, go to 'SQL Server Network Configuration' -> 'Protocols for
> [instance-name]'
>
> Right-click on both 'Named Pipes' and 'TCP/IP' and
> select 'enable'.

Double check TCP port:

> Double-click on 'TCP/IP'
>
> Select 'IP Addresses' tab
>
> Scroll to IPAII
> (down below and check TCP Port, it should be 1433 [default])

**Finally Restart the 'SQL Server ([instance-name])' services.**

Comment: Hi CR241, thank you for the tip. I checked and both were disabled. I asked admin company to enable and the answer was:"*it's impossible as it is not a regular SQL server hosted on premises. The only access you have is over TCP/IP".

Comment: Does it proceed?

Comment: It's not ideal case, at least try connect after TCP/IP 'enable'. usually TCP Protocol is good in practice,If still it's not working I don't know the reason..

Comment: The server is running outside my Office, I looged only through  Management Studio. SQL Server Config. is looking at my local server, which has nothing. Any guesses on how can I check if it is Enabled on the other server?